# Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified (Tried many things but couldn't find solution)

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

This question is already on Stack Overflow. But nobody solve my issue.

When I open my webpage (on my uploaded website on server) in which I am using database connectivity below error comes -

http://puneetchawla-001-site1.smarterasp.net/blog.aspx

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Searched on Google and found many thing and applied it but no one solved my issue.

1. Windows service called "SQL Server Browser" and start the service (I have enabled it).
2. Enabled incoming port TCP 1433 ( I have done this).

My web.config file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
<add name="myWebsite" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=myWebsite;Integrated Security=True; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have uploaded my website here - http://www.smarterasp.net

and their connection string samples for MSSQL are below-

```
"Data Source=SQL5014.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9D58DA_myWebsite;User Id=DB_9D58DA_myWebsite_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"
```

I did changes in web.config based on our samples but didn't get solution.

I think, there will be only changes in web.config and rest all are correct.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Management Studio on your system? I so try to login into SQL server using it . Use the windows credentials.

Comment: Hi @DhruvJoshi. Sorry for delay reply. Yes, it login proper on Window Authentication. I have added link on my question. Check it, it may helps you to for solving issue.

Comment: Nobody can give suggestions to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had not written the connection string (as specified in sample) in web.config file.
Your web.config file should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
<add name="myWebsite" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5014.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9D58DA_myWebsite;User Id=DB_9D58DA_myWebsite_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;" />  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Just change your web.config file and you will get the solution.